# Is JAVA NIO wasting CPU cycles by looping continuously?

Tags: java, multithreading, nio

Code for an echo server using  a single threaded java I/O

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // create socket
    int port = 4444;
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    System.err.println("Started server on port " + port);

    try {

        // repeatedly wait for connections, and process
        while (true) {

            // a "blocking" call which waits until a connection is requested
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.err.println("Accepted connection from client");

            // open up IO streams
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            PrintStream out = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

            // waits for data and reads it in until connection dies
            // readLine() blocks until the server receives a new line from client
            String s;
            while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
                out.print(s);
            }

            // close IO streams, then socket
            System.err.println("Closing connection with client");
            out.close();
            in.close();
            clientSocket.close();
        }
    } finally {
        serverSocket.close();
    }

}
```

code for the same using NIO

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocketChannel server = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    server.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(PORT_NUMBER));
    server.socket().setReuseAddress(true);
    server.configureBlocking(false);

    Selector selector = Selector.open();
    server.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(BUFFER_SIZE);
    while (true) {
        int channelCount = selector.select();
        if (channelCount > 0) {
            Set<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys();
            Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator = keys.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = iterator.next();
                iterator.remove();

                if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                    SocketChannel client = server.accept();
                    client.configureBlocking(false);
                    client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ, client.socket().getPort());
                } else if (key.isReadable()) {
                    SocketChannel client = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                    System.out.println("port: " + key.attachment());
                    if (client.read(buffer) < 0) {
                        key.cancel();
                        client.close();
                    } else {
                        buffer.flip(); // read from the buffer
                          /*
                           * byte[] received = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
                           * buffer.get(received); buffer.clear(); // write into the buffer
                           * buffer.put(received); buffer.flip(); // read from the buffer
                           */
                        client.write(buffer);
                        buffer.clear(); // write into the buffer
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here using normal I/O the main thread comes and wait at the socket.accept() call. But NIO doesn't do that since socketChannel.accept() is not a blocking call.

So wont the NIO program be continuously running the loop ? And result in waste of CPU cycles ? Can I write the program in a better way. Sorry I am very new to JAVA NIO and asynchronous programming.

Comment: Java NIO does not loop continuously. Your code might, but then it would be your code that is wasting CPU cycles, not Java NIO. NB There is nothing [tag:asynchronous] here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In normal IO the thread is blocked on `serverSocket.accept()`.

With NIO the thread is blocked on `selector.select()`.

From the JavaDoc of [`Selector#select()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html#select()):

> This method performs a **blocking** selection operation.

---

**Why is this called "non blocking IO"?**

Actually, your first example (with normal IO) has two blocking calls: `server.accept()` and `in.readLine()`.

Now consider the case with a badly behaving client: it opens a connection to the server, but never sends any data. With normal IO the server thread waits in `in.readLine()` for data to arrive and cannot serve any other client until the first client closes its connection.

With NIO the picture is different: if a client opens a connection, the server thread wakes up, `server.accept()`s the connection and registers the `SocketChannel` with the same selector. Then the server thread waits on the selector once more through `selector.select()`. Now there are two possibilities to wake up the server thread: either another client connecting, or the first client sending some data.

So the term "non blocking IO" does not mean that the server thread is never blocked - it means that a non-behaving client cannot block the server thread forever.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Didnt know that Selector#select is a blocking call. Then why is it called an Non Blocking IO , When one of its API actually blocks -_- Sorry about my ignorance.

Comment: @Ajay if added some more explanatory text. I hope to have made clearer the point about non-blocking IO - otherwise don't hesitate to ask again

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining it clearly Thomas. I understood it clearly now. Thanks for spending your time on my query.